# How to add a CheckBox in the office 2016 - Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365

How to add a CheckBox in the office 2016 - Word?  When the user click on the box, the box should get checked. How do i add the check box in the word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize the ribbon and enable the Developer ribbon. The Developer ribbon has the controls that can be added to a page. After adding the control, you need to click Review ribbon > Restrict Editing and allow filling in forms. The screenshot shows how. Then click the button "Yes, start enforcing protection" and save the document.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @teylyn... i was able to add check box.. i am using office 2016 in MacBook.. I couldn't see the Restricting Editing - Format Editing under Review Tab..

Comment: If you use Mac, please indicate that in your question. Mac is always different and often inferior, i.e. does not have functionality that Windows has.

Comment: thank you so much !! I am able to achieve in word 2007 in windows.  Now, how do i group Yes No Check box. Right now, i am able to select both the boxes. I need the option to select either one.